MAUI Android Javax.Crypto.AEADBadTagException
I have my .NET 8 MAUI application and I tried to deploy it on a real Android device after updating MAUI to the version 8.0.82
When the application starts I get this error

Javax.Crypto.AEADBadTagException


I understood the error comes from changes from the SecurityStorage in the Maui Essentials. On GitHub, I read that the workaround is to set to False in the AndroidManifest the backup like that
<application android:allowBackup="false" 
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/auto_backup_rules" 
    android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:supportsRtl="true" 
    android:label="Language In Use" 
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/appcenter_backup_rule">

but I continue to receive the message and I can't run the application. Checking the preview documentation, I read I have to update also the auto_backup_rules.xml like the following
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>
    <include domain="sharedpref" path="."/>
    <exclude domain="sharedpref" 
             path="${applicationId}.microsoft.maui.essentials.preferences.xml"/>
</full-backup-content>

but it is not working. How can I fix this issue?

When using the second method, do you set android:fullBackupContent=“@xml/auto_backup_rules” and remove android:allowBackup=“false” in AndroidManifest.xml?

Yes and it is not working. I removed both (fullBackupContent and allowBackup) with the same error. If I leave android:allowBackup="true" and remove fullBackupContent the error continues to be there.

After a lot of trials, setting android:allowBackup="false" was enough to fix the issue. Why didn't it work before, I don't know. I deploy the application on a new phone (meaning a phone with Android 14 where the app wasn't deploy previously) and the app is working.

You can post this solution as an answer, which will help others who encounter the similar problem.
